# Computer boots in safemode but get BSoD in normal mode

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

For my grandparents I installed my old computer with the harddisks from their computer. Now the problem is when I try to boot I get a BSoD and then it instants restarts the computer.

If I run in safe mode everything works perfectly. Because of this I thought it was a driver problem. So I removed the old ATI drivers and installed the correct graphic card drivers.

But this didn't fix the problem. What I got now is when I try to load safe mode or normal mode I see black screen with an underscore blinking. Safe mode still works but normal mode it just restarts automatically.

I have no idea what the problem is but I assume it some software on the HDs that is conflicting with the graphics card? The computer runs on Windows XP SP3.

Help pls :(

Thx!

Comment: If your getting a BSOD. After turing the PC on tap F8 once a second until you get a boot menu.  Select "Disable automatic reboot........" Then "Start Normally". There should be a STOP code what is it?

Comment: The problem is and can only be driver-related. `I installed my old computer with the harddisks from their computer`. Besides graphics drivers, there are a lot of other drivers present in any installation of Windows. try to uninstall all drivers referring to the previous computer and installing all drivers corresponding to the actual computer running the disks.

Comment: In your case 80% of the time its the hard drive controller issue.  You need to revert it to "Standard IDE mode".  If it were just the graphics you could press F8 and select "Standard VGA" and the computer would boot VGA and you could load the new drivers easy.

Comment: Follow @Doktoro Reichard 's suggestion. The fact that you can successfully boot into safe mode points to a driver problem.

Comment: Ok thx, I will try these things tomorrow!

Comment: Check this answer as it fits your issue almost completely http://superuser.com/questions/655680/transferring-ide-hard-disk-to-sata-only-motherboard/655686#655686

Comment: The disk controller drivers are wrong.  You can try changing the SATA emulation mode in the BIOS to compatibility and see if it boots then.  Otherwise you should backup their data, install windows fresh and migrate the data either manually or via windows easy transfer.

Comment: boot into safe mode (with network) and upload the dmp fiels from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: I installed all drivers except the ones for SATA since the one I downloaded doesn't work. But no succes yet. Is there anyway I can safely transfer all programs/data to a fresh windows install?

Comment: again, upload the dmp files, otherwise we can't see what is wrong with your PC.

Comment: Well, There are no DMP files. Atleast not in Minidump :O

Comment: do you see a file called **Memory.dmp** under C:\Windows?